How to fix "Invalid value for purpose." error when using Azure OpenAI GPT 4o mini batch?
I try to use Azure OpenAI GPT 4o mini batch. I first need to create the batch. I ran:
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI

client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key="[insert Azure OpenAI API key here]",
    api_version="2023-07-01-preview",
    azure_endpoint="https://[insert Azure OpenAI API enddpoint here].openai.azure.com/",
)


file = client.files.create(
    file=open("./dummy.jsonl", "rb"),
    purpose="batch"
)
file_id = file.id

with dummy.jsonl containing:
{
    "custom_id": "request-1",
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/v1/chat/completions",
    "body": {
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125",
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": "You are a helpful assistant."
            },
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": "Hello world!"
            }
        ],
        "max_tokens": 1000
    }
}

I get the error:
BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'code': 'invalidPayload', 'message': 'Invalid value for purpose.'}}

How to fix that error?

To make the code work, upgrade the api_version. E.g., the following works:
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI

client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key="[insert Azure OpenAI API key here]",
    api_version="2023-07-01-preview",
    azure_endpoint="https://[insert Azure OpenAI API enddpoint here].openai.azure.com/",
)

file = client.files.create(
    file=open("./dummy.jsonl", "rb"),
    purpose="batch"
)
file_id = file.id

